# A service like Usabilityhub's Navflow but featuring branching?

Tags: interaction-design, usability-testing, tools

For testing navigation flows of static screens/image mockups [Usabilityhub's Navflow](http://navflow.com/) is a pretty nifty service/tool.

However, to my knowledge it only allows the test creator to specify one single path of images.

- I'm looking for a service/tool similar to Navflow but featuring branching
  to different subsequent images depending on where on the
  "parent" image a test participant has clicked - **does anybody know
  of such?**

Answer (score 1):

[InVision](http://www.invisionapp.com/) will let you do this, I think:

> Design In Your Tool of Choice
> InVision simply requires .jpg, .png or .gif files. Create them however you want.
>
> Drag 'n' Drop
> Take your static files and drop them right into InVision all at once. The bulk uploader makes adding files a snap.
>
> Draw Hotspots & Link 'em up
> Linking screens together couldn't be easier. Simply draw a hotspot and select a target screen for that button to click through to.

It looks like you upload images and then use their tool to define which parts of each image link to which other image.

However, it's a design tool, not a testing tool, so you probably can't do remote usability testing easily. You can however share a link to the wireframes so people can look through it and you could do usability testing by getting participants at the office to sit down and click around.

Comment: Thanks for input! Invision is something along the lines of what I'm looking for. However, it doesn't seem to provide the click-through testing capabilities I seek. It's more along the lines of textual feedback, whereas I need to investigate whether users understand a certain flow of interaction by tracking their paths. Also, it doesn't have the killer feature of Usabilityhub: The Karma points scheme for encouraging participation. Perhaps, I just have to wait for Angry Monkeys to extend Navflow (but I guess they're focusing on BugHerd at the moment) - or create such a service myself ;)